# Strapi graphql mutation Syntax Error: Unterminated string

Tags: vue.js, graphql, strapi

I always get `Syntax Error: Unterminated string` when I try to update my database using javascript strapi sdk. `this.chapter.content` is a html string generated by ckeditor. How can I escape this string to update my database using graphql?

```
async updateChapter() {
      const q = `
            mutation {
              updateChapter(input: {
                where: {
                  id: "${this.$route.params.chapterId}"
                },
                data: {
                  content: "${this.chapter.content.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n')}"
                  title: "${this.chapter.title}"
                }
              }) {
                chapter{
                  title
                  id
                  content
                }
              }
            }
      `;
      const res = await strapi.request("post", "/graphql", {
        data: {
          query: q
        }
      });
      this.chapter = res.data.chapter;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you could use [block string notation](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-String-Value) to get around this issue. However, you really should supply dynamic input values using [variables](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Variables) instead of string interpolation. This way you can easily provide any of sort of values (strings, numbers, objects, etc.) and GraphQL will parse them accordingly -- including strings with line breaks.

```
const query = `
  mutation MyMutation ($chapterId: ID!, $content: String!, $title: String!) {
    updateChapter(input: {
      where: {
        id: $chapterId
      },
      data: {
        content: $content
        title: $title
      }
    }) {
      chapter{
        title
        id
        content
      }
    }
  }
`
const variables = {
  chapterId: '...',
  content: '...',
  title: '...',
}
const res = await strapi.request("post", "/graphql", {
  data: {
    query,
    variables,
  },
})
```

Note that `$chapterId` may need to be of the type `String!` instead if that's what's called for in the schema. Since variables can also be input object types, instead of providing 3 different variables, you could also provide a single variable to be passed to the `input` argument instead:

```
const query = `
  mutation MyMutation ($input: SomeInputObjectTypeHere!) {
    updateChapter(input: $input) {
      chapter{
        title
        id
        content
      }
    }
  }
`
const variables = {
  input: {
    where: {
      id: '...',
    },
    data: {
      content: '...',
      title: '...',
    },
  },
}
```

Again, just replace `SomeInputObjectTypeHere` with the appropriate type in your schema.

Comment: what does the 3 dots in variables do? should I change it?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for actual string values. You'd replace the string literal with a reference to some variables (like `this.chapter.title`). I just omitted that from the example for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution maybe help

Code with issue: For example mainReason and actionTaken fields are text inputs and data contains some white spaces. This action give error: Unterminated string

```
mutation { updateApplicationForm(input:{ where:{id:"${ticketData.id}"} 
data:{ 
  mainReason: "${ticketData.mainReason}"
  actionTaken: "${ticketData.actionTaken}"
  appStatus: ${ticketData.appStatus}
  action: "${ticketData.action}"
}
```

Fix this problem with JSON.stringify method

```
mutation { updateApplicationForm(input:{ where:{id:"${ticketData.id}"} 
  data:{ 
    mainReason:${JSON.stringify(ticketData.mainReason)} 
    actionTaken:${JSON.stringify(ticketData.actionTaken)}
    appStatus: ${ticketData.appStatus}
    action: "${ticketData.action}"
  }
```